# How to know when to create a composite constraint?

Tags: sql, model, constraints, ssms

I am currently learning SQL, and I have a physical data model I need to implement in code. However, during constraint creation, the numbers appearing next to FK and U started confusing me immensely. Consider [the diagram](http://prntscr.com/m5xdh6). EDIT: Added the full physical model.

I know that when the matter is Primary Keys, we must have a single PK Constraint that's all the columns marked as PK. However, when the thing is FK or Unique constraints, I'm not so sure myself.

Let's assume I want to create the FK constraints for the table Opcao.

Should I create a single constraint for multiple columns, referencing their respective columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MySchema.Opcao ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_SUPERKEY] FOREIGN KEY ([prova], [aluno], [pergunta], [dataRealizacao])
    REFERENCES MySchema.Integra([prova], [aluno], [pergunta], [dataRealizacao]);
```

Or create a constraint for each column, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MySchema.Opcao ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OPCAO_PROVA] FOREIGN KEY ([prova])
    REFERENCES MySchema.Integra([prova]);
ALTER TABLE MySchema.Opcao ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OPCAO_ALUNO] FOREIGN KEY ([aluno])
    REFERENCES MySchema.Integra([aluno]);
ALTER TABLE MySchema.Opcao ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OPCAO_PERGUNTA] FOREIGN KEY ([pergunta])
    REFERENCES MySchema.Integra([pergunta]);
ALTER TABLE MySchema.Opcao ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OPCAO_DATAREALIZACAO] FOREIGN KEY ([dataRealizacao])
    REFERENCES MySchema.Integra([dataRealizacao]);
```

Would the Unique constraints follow the same logic? How do I know when to do one or the other?

Comment: It depends on how your reference table works.

Comment: I added the tables being referenced in the picture. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a foreign key consisting of three columns which have to match all the three columns in the referenced table?
Then you should use in my oppinion on constraint for the three columns, because its the semantic you want to tell.
The one constraint for each column approach has the same effect, but you have to think a little to get the intension.

Some other tips: I don't get the semantic of the schema because i don't know the language the entities are named in. It would be easier if they were named in english. One thing i saw is the pergunta column which is duplicated and needs to be consistent in opcao, Integra und Pergunta table, this may lead to problems.
I generally helped me to always make an artifical auto increment primary key for every table (even the join tables for n to m relations), and always reference this artificial key. Then you have less problems (with case insensitivity for example) and the schema is in my oppinion easier to understand.